# Serialize XML adding extra element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Having alot of trouble serializing this. Very new to serlializing in XML

Here is where I'm writing to the classes of data thats serialized.

```
    string addrID="Sante Fe, New Mexico";
              INPUT r = new INPUT();
              INPUTLOG ls = new INPUTLOG();
              ls.id = id;
              ls.password = password;
              r.LOGIN = ls;
              REQUESTaddr l = new REQUESTaddr();
              l.loan_id = addrID;
              INPUTLOGINREQ r = new INPUTLOGINREQ();
              r.LOAN = l;
              loan.REQUEST = r;

              string serializedSearch = doSerializationsearch(r);   

private static string doSerializationsearch(INPUT r)
    {
        string serializedValue = string.Empty;


            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(r.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(ms, r);

                ms.Position = 0;
                var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                serializedValue = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }


            serializedValue = serializedValue.Replace("version=\"0\"", string.Empty).Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>", string.Empty).Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", string.Empty);


        return serializedValue;
    }
```

For some reason its serializing it to this with an addridfield element which I don't want.

```
<INPUT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
  <LOGIN api_user_id="user" api_password="password" />   
    <REQUEST>      
      <Address addr_id="53196d9f4c544e4da9f647b2c86444c2">       
      <addridField>53196d9f4c544e4da9f647b2c86444c2</addridField>  <<<<<I do not want this
      </Address>    
   </REQUEST> 
 </INPUT>
```

I don't notice anythign wrong with my classes to my eye but anyone else notice something that I'm doing wrong to add this extra element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the field `addridField` inside the `REQUESTaddr` class private, instead of public.  XMLSerializer will serialize ALL the **public** properties and fields.

Comment: ugh...I was looking for awhile on what I did...Thank You for the fresh pair of eyes

Comment: Or mark it with the `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]`attribute if you need it to be public